# Trying to establish a connection

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have just downloaded and extracted the Oracle SQLDeveloper in MAC OS X. Until then, when I am establishing a connection using the HR (default) as the username and password, ORCL for the SID... the test result always show "test failed the network adapter could not establish the connection". Any insights...

regards prinsipeluha

Comment: You need to narrow the possible problem areas to get a good answer.  First, did you ever connect successfully to the Oracle DB?  If so, using what?  If not, is the Oracle Server local or remote?  The more detail you can provide, the better the answers will be.

Answer (score 1):

Your Host or Port entry is not correct and/or your host is not accessible from your machine (e.g. behind a firewall).  If localhost the defaults would be

```
host:  localhost
port:  1521
```